# Two API in same controller trying to access one helper method at a time causes any multi thread issues

Tags: spring, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a controller, for example, `EmployeeController`,

`findEmployeesByDepartment` and `findLevelOneEmployeesByDepartment` are using a common private method `getDepartmentId` which returns `Long`

If two requests or threads access this private method, is there a possibility for the value to get changed which is called by the two methods.

A simple doubt

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/emp")
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping("/emp/dept/")
    public Employee findEmployeesByDepartment(Department department) {
        Long id = getDepartmentId(department);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/emp/dept/")
    public Employee findLevelOneEmployeesByDepartment(Department department {
        Long id = getDepartmentId(department);
    }


    // private method
    private Long getDepartmentId(Department department) {
        ...
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: first thing, Request mapping url should be different ,it should not same.After that your doubt answer is "No" because changes will happen for the particular request object only based on your Department object.

Comment: if findEmployeesByDepartment and findLevelOneEmployeesByDepartment are accessed at same time then ?

Comment: both requests will get same response because it seems you are fetching data.

Comment: Then it's a  wrong approach, basically, different Department objects are sent as a parameter expecting different ids right?

Answer (score 1):

Different calls to `getDepartmentId` has different method stack trace, they are in different memory space, which means they are separated.

So, if you did not

- share any variable between different `Department`
- use any variable declared as class field in `getDepartmentId`

`getDepartmentId` will be thread-safe.

### Example

Let's say you expect an increment id for every new `Department`, and you use some shared varibale in `getDepartmentId` without synchronization:

```
Long id = new Long(0);

private Long getDepartmentId(Department department){
    id++;
    return id;
}
```

They may get the same `id`, not increment one.

To gurantee thread-safe in this case, you need some extra operation such as `synchronized` key word:

```
private synchronized Long getDepartmentId(Department department){
    id++;
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, If possible can you give some example or elaborate on these two points, please . "So, if you did not
share any variable between different Department
use any variable declared as a class field in getDepartmentId "

Comment: Great, Thanks, for example, if a class is instantiated in that method then it's better to use ThreadLocal? something like                                  
 private Long getDepartmentId(Department department){
    Employee emp = new Employee(department)
    return emp.getId();
}

Comment: @CorkKochi That's not necessary. Objects declared and instantiated in method is thread local.  You only need declare it explicitly when it is class level variable.

Comment: Ok Thanks, that make sense